# how to sort vector<vector<int>>

Tags: c++, stl

I wrote a compare() function to sort `vector< vector < int > >` and it crashes.

Specifically, if I call `sort(u.begin(),u.end());` no crash happens. However if I call `sort(u.begin(),u.end(), compare);` It crashed, even if `compare()` simply returns `true` with no more code. What is wrong with my code?

```
bool compare_4sum(vector<int>& a, vector<int>& b){
    return true;
}

void test(){    
    vector<int> x; 
    x.push_back(1);
    x.push_back(2);
    vector<int> x2;
    x2.push_back(2);
    x2.push_back(4);    
    vector<vector<int>> u;    
    u.push_back(x);
    u.push_back(x2);
    sort(u.begin(),u.end(), compare);
}
```

Comment: I do believe the below answers correctly _guess_ what the problem is. But if it indeed is the problem, the program does _not_ crash but _asserts_. And almost certainly _tells_ you what the problem is. So if you described _how_ it "crashes", we could be certain and just explain to you what and why. -1 for not doing so.

Comment: I think there is no crash - just compilation fails !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your comparison function must provide a [strict-weak ordering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_ordering#Strict_weak_orderings).  If it does not, then your call to sort exhibits undefined behavior.

25.4/3 & 4

> 3) For all algorithms that take Compare, there is a version that uses
>   operator< instead. That is, comp(*i,*j) != false defaults to *i < *j
>   != false. For algorithms other than those described in 25.4.3 to work
>   correctly, comp has to induce a strict weak ordering on the values.
>
> 4) The term strict refers to the requirement of an irreflexive
>   relation (!comp(x, x) for all x), and the term weak to requirements
>   that are not as strong as those for a total ordering, but stronger
>   than those for a partial ordering. If we define equiv(a, b) as
>   !comp(a, b) && !comp(b, a), then the requirements are that comp and
>   equiv both be transitive relations:
>
> > ```
> > — comp(a, b) && comp(b, c) implies comp(a, c)
> > — equiv(a, b) && equiv(b, c) implies equiv(a, c) [ Note: Under these conditions,
> >   it can be shown that
> >     — equiv is an equivalence relation
> >     — comp induces a well-defined relation on the equivalence classes determined
> >       by equiv
> >     — The induced relation is a strict total ordering. —end note ]
> > ```

Comment: I doubt this is the problem though. He only have to elements in the vector that he sorts. How would the return value (regardless is always true or false) be the cause here?

Comment: @MariusBancila: This obviously isn't his real code, since it doesn't compile.  But given the information, it is the only explanation I can see.  There may be other problems, but they are not indicated here.  And it's not the return value of the comparison function that will cause the problem (not directly, at least), it is the sorting algorithm, which makes assumptions about the comparison function.  Who knows what those assumptions might cause the algorithm to do, if the assumptions are false?  He might even be referring to a debug assertion as a crash.

Comment: @ Ben: I replaced the code : return true to sth. else like if (a.size()>b.size()) return true; else if a.size()<b.size() return false; return a[0] < b[0]; it passed. however, if I replaced with the code I want to implement. it crashed at VC's system file xutility.c: line 677: else if (_Pred(_Right, _Left)) _DEBUG_ERROR2("invalid operator<", _File, _Line); I do not understand why. If you happen to know what this error mean please let me know otherwise I am fine because it seems the error is due to the code I am working on not the sort() or vector of VC. Thanks

Comment: @user389955 It means that the compiler did a check on your comparator to see if it met the qualifications of a strict-weak ordering function, and it failed.

Answer (score 6):

It likely crashes because a comparison function for sort must follow a [strict weak ordering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_ordering). Your comparison fails on just about all accounts:

> For all x, it is not the case that x < x

This will obviously fail.

> For all x, y, if x < y then it is not the case that y < x

`compare_4sum(x, y)` will be `true`, as will `compare_4sum(y, x)`, hence breaking this.

And so on down the list. You must be very careful when writing predicates for use in `std::sort` that they do not break this contract, otherwise you're likely to get crashes.

Also, any comparison function should never modify the values it operates on, hence you should always be passing by `const &`, not `&`.

Comment: @ Yuushi: I replaced the code : return true to sth. else like if (a.size()>b.size()) return true; else if a.size()<b.size() return false; return a[0] < b[0]; it passed.  however, if I replaced with the code I want to implement. it crashed at VC's system file xutility.c: line 677: else if (_Pred(_Right, _Left))
  _DEBUG_ERROR2("invalid operator<", _File, _Line); I do not understand why. If you happen to know what this error mean please let me know otherwise I am fine because it seems the error is  due to the code I am working on not the sort() or vector of VC. Thanks.